# Android format a UTC datetime string into local format throws null error

Tags: android, datetime

hi I have the method below which takes the value of a UTC datetime string, format it to local display and return:

```
public static String convertDateStringUTCToLocal(String sourceUtcDateTimeString)
{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    simpleDataFormat.setTimeZone(getCurrentTimeZone());
    String outputUTCDateTimeString = simpleDataFormat.parse(sourceUtcDateTimeString, new ParsePosition(0)).toString();

    return outputUTCDateTimeString;
}

public static TimeZone getCurrentTimeZone()
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone outputTimeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();

    return outputTimeZone;
}
```

I use getCurrentTimeZone() because user may change their local setting anytime and I don't want to hard code the format.

While debugging, the value of parameter sourceUtcDateTimeString is 'Mon Apr 15 13:54:00 GMT 2013', I found that 'simpleDataFormat.parse(sourceUtcDateTimeString, new ParsePosition(0))' gives me 'null', and 'simpleDataFormat.parse(sourceUtcDateTimeString, new ParsePosition(0)).toString()' throws error "java.lang.NullPointerException at toString()".

Looks like there is nothing at ParsePosition(0), but I am really new to Android dev, no idea why this is happening and how to get around it, could any one help out with a fix? I got stuck on this issue for hours.

thanks in advance.

Comment: i recommend you read SimpleDateFormat documentation, and in particular the documentation of the default constructor.

Comment: Try changing this line `String outputUTCDateTimeString = simpleDataFormat.parse(sourceUtcDateTimeString, new ParsePosition(0)).toString();` with this one `String outputUTCDateTimeString = simpleDataFormat.parse(sourceUtcDateTimeString).toString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the string you are trying to parse comes from a `Date`'s `toString()` method, which gives the format `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy` (see [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29)). To parse that back to a `Date` you can either use `Date parsed = new Date(Date.parse())`, which is deprecated, or use a `SimpleDateFormat` with the format `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` (see [SimpleDateFormat Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).

For example this code works for me:

```
public static String convertDateStringUTCToLocal(String sourceUtcDateTimeString)
{
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDataFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    // SimpleDateFormat already uses the default time zone, no need to set it again
    String outputUTCDateTimeString = simpleDataFormat.parse(sourceUtcDateTimeString, new ParsePosition(0)).toString();

    return outputUTCDateTimeString;
}
```

Depending on the rest of you application you should consider passing around any dates as a `Date` instance rather than using a `String`. You can then simply apply the right format any time you need to display the date to the user.

Comment: edited the answer, because I missed the `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"` in the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor